# Android: image from assets saved as bitmap is corrupted

Tags: android, file, bitmap, android-intent, save

i'm trying to take an image from assets (assets not drawable to have subfolders due to high amount of pictures) and want it to be opened with an ACTION_VIEW intent. Since i don't know any other way i'm trying to take the image as a bitmap, save to cache as a jpg file, open and delete when its closed. (Is there any other way?)

Unfortunately, it saves a file, but it is corruped image file, emulator opens black image, phone shows error image, computer says the image file is corrupted. Anything bad in my code?

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
AssetManager mngr = getAssets();
                try {
                    InputStream is2 = mngr.open(type+"/"+type+""+mRowId+".jpg");
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2);
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    OutputStream outStream = null;
                    File file = new File(ShowActivity.this.getCacheDir(), type+""+mRowId+".jpg");
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);


                      boolean compressed = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, outStream);
                       outStream.flush();
                       outStream.close();


                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String patht = ShowActivity.this.getCacheDir().getName() + File.separatorChar+type+""+mRowId+".jpg";
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(patht)), "image/jpg");
                startActivity(intent);
```

EDIT:

seems like the code is working but i get the following error in logcat:

```
12-09 15:17:02.568: INFO/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent                    { 
act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///cache/12.jpg typ=image/jpeg cmp=com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ViewImage } from pid 378
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389): got exception decoding bitmap
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at com.android.camera.Util.makeInputStream(Util.java:336)
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:307)
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:299)
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:94)
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:86)
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.thumbBitmap(UriImage.java:120)
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.executeRequest(ImageGetter.java:173)
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.run(ImageGetter.java:149)
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389): got exception decoding bitmap 
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at com.android.camera.Util.makeInputStream(Util.java:336)
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:307)
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:299)
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:94)
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.executeRequest(ImageGetter.java:204)
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.run(ImageGetter.java:149)
12-09 15:17:02.728: ERROR/UriImage(389):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-09 15:17:03.717: INFO/ActivityManager(61): Displayed com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ViewImage: +1s58ms
```

Comment: no idea, can you explain on that. Anyway should the problem be elsewhere since it creates a file, ant not empty, it just doesn`t open as an image

Comment: May not be your problem (I'm just trying to get a feel for your design pattern), but generally I run a `Thread` when saving.

Comment: I save image with this code to SD - it works.

Comment: edited and included the error, it creates the file correctly now, something wrong with opening it

Comment: Try save to SD, not cache dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it work, saving to sd made no difference. It turned out the code was ok, but FilOutputStream creates the file with default permissions which ACTION_VIEW can`t open. Changing FileOutputStream to openFileOutput helped:

```
InputStream is2 = mngr.open(type+"/"+type+""+mRowId+".jpg");
                    Log.v(TAG, type+" "+mRowId);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2);
                    FileOutputStream outStream = openFileOutput(type+""+mRowId+"cache.jpg", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                    boolean compressed = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, outStream);
                    jpg = getFileStreamPath(type+""+mRowId+"cache.jpg");
                    outStream.close();
```

...

```
                 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(jpg), "image/jpeg");
```